# Spock extension's start method invoked multiple times

Tags: testing, spock, geb

I have bunch of functional tests based on Spock and Geb. I want to perform some actions before and after execution of these tests. So I created global extension and added required functionality to start() and stop() methods of that extension. But the problem is that start/stop methods are invoked before/after each Spock spec though Spock documentation (http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_global_extensions) states:

> start() This is called once at the very start of the Spock execution
>
> stop() This is called once at the very end of the Spock execution

Do I do something wrong or Spock documentation is incorrect about behaviour of these methods?

Comment: Could you give more information about how you are running the tests. (Maven/Gradle/...)

Comment: I run tests using 'mvn clean test' command. I guess it is by design to invoke start/stop methods before/after each specification because I use Spock reports library which is implemented also as global extension and it works same way. But maybe there are other ways how to achieve what I need i.e. invoke some actions once just before starting all test specifications and after finishing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MantasG Spock implements a JUnit Runner and does not control how it is executed. Global extensions are managed in a `RunContext` which is kept in a `ThreadLocal`. If surefire uses multiple threads to execute Tests then this will create multiple instances of `RunContext` each with their own list of global extensions. If you are using an `EmbeddedSpecRunner` then this would also create a new isolated context.

> This context will stay around until the thread dies.   It would be
>   more accurate to remove the context once the test run   has finished,
>   but the JUnit Runner SPI doesn't provide an adequate hook.   That
>   said, since most environments fork a new JVM for each test run,   this
>   shouldn't be much of a problem in practice.

Depending on what you want to do there are other ways:

1. you can use a [JUnitRunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) and use the `testRunStarted`/`testRunFinished` hooks. Note that you need to register this via surefire.
2. If you really want to run only once, then you could use failsafe instead of surefire and use the pre- and postintegration goals.
3. You could hack something using a static fields and a counter for each `start`/`stop` call and perform your start action if the counter is 0 and perform your stop action once the counter reaches 0. Of course you'll need to make this thread safe.

Note that surefire also supports [forking multiple JVMs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) and this will also impact options 1 and 3.

Comment: Thank you Leonard, your answer is very comprehensive. All suggested options could be used to achieve what I need but in my case none of these worked because I had '<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>' in my Surefire configuration. After I switched to 'reuseForks=true' everything started to work. Now I'm even able to use Spock extension to implement what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Spock is invoked at the start of every Testing Spec in your testing Suite, so start and stop are run with every one of those executions

I think you might want to take a look at the Fixture Methods found in the same doc you linked in the question:
http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_specification